# NDIS filter driver doesn't load in windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, device-driver, code-signing, wdk, ndis

I'm trying to develop an NDIS filter driver. However, I don't seem to be able to load it.
I have the `debug` and `testsigning` boot options enabled; my driver is test-signed, and the certificate is loaded in the `root` and `trustedpublisher` stores.

Before I enabled `testsigning`, my driver would show up in ntbootlog.txt as

> Did not load driver \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\mydriver.sys

After I enabled `testsigning`, the driver doesn't show up at all. It is, however, presented in the interface proprties. The interface is broken until I disable my filter, even though my driver is currently a very minimal pass-through NDIS filter driver. When I disable my filter, everything works fine again.

The driver is not listed in windbg's module list, but it *is* listed in the "unloaded modules" list, which suggests the driver was loaded at some point.
My driver produces some output during `DriverEntry` and `DriverUnload`, as well as in all mandatory NDIS hooks. None of this output shows up in windbg's `!dbgprint`, which suggests the driver's `DriverEntry` has never been called.

I'm at a loss how to debug this issue; Could anyone give me some hints as to what might be going on here?

I'm using Windows 2008 R2 DataCenter, checked build. I'm currently limited to a single machine setup.

Comment: Starting over with from an example driver solved the problem for me. 

All the answers below seemed to a assume the Driver Entry was invoked, while that was clearly not the case

Answer (score 0):

Try to first load a simple driver that only print a trace string in DriverEntry, test sign it and load it. If you see the trace we'll try to understand what's wrong with your particular driver. If not, maybe kernel tracing is disabled for your system and your NDIS driver isn't loaded because of a problem, which you cant see of course, because system traces are disabled.

Comment: I'm writing a debug message as the first thing in the DriverEntry. It doesn't show up in the dbgprint buffer.

Comment: By default DbgPrint() outputs are disabled in Vista/Server2008. You may follow the below setting in registry to enable the debug prints.

Open up the registry and go to this path, “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter” and add the following value “DEFAULT” : REG_DWORD : 0xFFFFFFFF and then reboot. You may have to create the “Debug Print Filter” key if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If the driver shows up in unloaded module list then it got loaded.

If you use `DbgPrint` make sure you read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543632%28VS.85%29.aspx) documentation, specifically the section about filtering.

To catch the driver loading you can use `sxe ld:mydriver` this will allow you to set breakpoints in your driver entry.    Another easy way to debug this is to put a hard-coded breakpoint in DriverEntry `DbgBreakPoint()`